# How to change strings in list into uppercase in Python 3.4.3?

Tags: python, list

When I'm trying add

```
[x.upper() for x in b]
```

nothing happened. I know that

```
x.upper()
```

is not intendef for lists, but maybe it can be somehow do. It's not my homework.

```
import random

a = ["po", "ko", "do", "to"]
b = ["ab", "cd", "ef", "gh"]

[x.upper() for x in b]

def ran():

for i in range(0,1):
    random.shuffle(a)
    print(a[0], "\n", a[1], "\n", a[2], "\n", a[3])


for y in range(0,1):
    random.shuffle(b)
    print(b[0], "\n", b[1], "\n", b[2], "\n", b[3])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement

```
[x.upper() for x in b]
```

would just return a new list.

You must assign it to some variable as

```
b = [x.upper() for x in b]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list comprehension generates a list. You need to reassign it to the original list `b` if you want that original list to be changed. It does not do an in-place modification.

```
b = [x.upper() for x in b]
```